# Help in understanding a proof of Milne about the order of a product of elements in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm reading the proof of Theorem 1.64 in http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GT.pdf

my questions are

1) Why don't we immediately start with a prime $p$ not dividing $mnr$? Using the same strategy it seems we get elements of order $m$,$n$ with product of order $r$ directly in the group $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$. Why is the 2 important?

2) Why in the definition of $a$ there is an $u^{-1}$ and in the definition of $b$ a $v^{-1}$? Why don't we define $a$ to be $\begin{pmatrix} u&1\\0&u\end{pmatrix}$ and $b$ to be $\begin{pmatrix}v&0\\t&v\end{pmatrix}$ with $t$ such that $2uv+t=w+w^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Question 1, the group in which we are finding elements of these orders is not ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb F}_q)$ but ${\rm PSL}(2,{\mathbb F}_q)$, and so you choose an element of order $2m$ in ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb F}_q)$ in order for its image to have order $m$ in  ${\rm PSL}(2,{\mathbb F}_q)$. The argument will not work in ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb F}_q)$ if any of $m,n,r$ is $2$, because $-I_2$ is the only element of ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb F}_q)$ of order $2$, and that lies in the centre.

The answer to the second question is that the elements $a$ and $b$ must have determinant $1$ for them to lie in ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb F}_q)$.

Comment: I understand your answers, my only remaining doubt is: where does the proof break if I try to follow that strategy to find elements of order $m,n,r$ in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$? I can find elements $v,u,w$ in $\mathbb{F}_q^*$ of order $m,n,r$, and by constructing those matrices don't I get elements of the same order?

Comment: As I said, the only element of order $2$ is $-I_2$, which is central, so if $a$ and $b$ have order $2$ then $ab = I_2$. Hence the argument cannot possibly work when $m=n=2$. It works in ${\rm SL}(n,q)$ provided that $m,n,r$ are all greater than $2$.

Comment: I see that I was just wondering where the proof breaks. Let's assume that we don't know $-I_2$ is the only element of order 2. Find a prime $p$ that doesn't divide $mnr$, then there is a power of $p$, $q$, such that $mnr$ divides $q-1$, so we can find elements $u,v,w$ in $F_q^*$ of order $m,n,r$ respectively. Define the matrices $a=\begin{pmatrix} u&1\\0&u^{-1}\end{pmatrix},b=\begin{pmatrix} v&0\\t&v^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$ where $t$ is such that $uv+t+u^{-1}v^{-1}=w+w^{-1}$, then the order of $a$ is $m$, the order of $b$ is $n$ and the order of $ab$ is $r$. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Since you know the result is wrong, you should be able to find the mistake yourself by following the incorrect example through the proof. Try it with $m=2$ and see what you get for $a$. Is the order of $a$ really $2$?

Comment: It is not similar to a diagonal matrix when $m=2$. It is otherwise. This is just elementary linear algebra.

Comment: got it, thanks.